# php using class based on string

Tags: php, laravel

you suppose we have a simple string as class name and namespace, for example:

```php
$className = "post";
$nameSpace = "\\App\\Models\\";
$class     = $nameSpace.Str::studly($className);
```

my question is how can i use this variables to use `Laravel`, methods such as `find`, for example:

```php
//$data = Post::find(1);
$data = $class()::find(1);
```

here we can make a new stance from this string but i want to use `Model` function features.

i get this error:

```
Error
Call to undefined function App\Models\Post()
```

Comment: Well, `Model()::find(1)` is an error (Call to undefined method `Model()`), but did you simply try `$class::find(1)`?

Comment: @TimLewis i think that worked, let me test more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
$class = "\\App\\Models\\Post";
$class     = new $class;
$data = $class->find(1);
```

Or, as [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3965631/tim-lewis) said:

```
$class = "\\App\\Models\\Post";
$data = $class::find(1);
```

Comment: You don't even need `$class = new $class;`, simply `$class = "\\App\\Models\\Post";` then  `$data = $class::find(1);` works just fine.

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, I saw your comment just after post my answer, you're right

Comment: Cool, answer looks good :) Demonstrates accessing `find()` via static call and class instance call, good stuff!